# FabricJS text color is object

Tags: json, fabricjs

I am trying to load the text color in a color picker. However, when I do get("fill") on the activeobject I loaded from JSON, it gives me an object. Here is the offending JSON line:

```
"fill":{"ok":true,"format":"hex6","_tc_id":258,"alpha":1}
```

How am I supposed to turn that into a color and not an object Object?

Adding jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qb4Xe/5/

Just click on the text!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, the problem is that you are restoring the canvans by loading a json that contains a wrong value for the `fill` property, explicitly:

```
 "fill":{"ok":true,"format":"hex6","_tc_id":258,"alpha":1}
```

probably this object is coming  from the serialization of a [TinyColor](http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/)

Unfortunately this can not be interpreted correctly by fabricjs and can not be converted back into a hex color (see the [sources of TinyColor](https://raw.github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js) if you need to delve this point )

I create this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZBTM/1/) to shows how it is possible to reproduce a similar mistake; suppose we have a TinyColor

```
var t = tinycolor("#ff0000");
```

We make a **mistake** if we use this TinyColor object as the value of the fill property ( i.e. `fill: t` ), for example:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: t, top: 100, left: 100 }));
```

by serializing the canvas we get a JSON that contains:

```
"fill":{"ok":true,"format":"hex","_tc_id":0,"alpha":1},
```

but this can not work and the actual `fill` is visualized as black ( the default ) instead of our color ( red ).

**The  correct approach is** to use **`fill: t.toHexString()`**:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: t.toHexString(),  top: 150, left: 150 }))
```

this works fine ( the rectangle is red ) moreover by serializing the canvas we get a JSON that contains:

```
"fill":"#ff0000"
```

therefore this will work fine even when you will restore the canvans from JSON.

**EDIT**

Ultimately suggest is to fix the problem at the origini, **but** if you have to deal with a buggy json string also is possible to intercept the problem this way:

```
if (typeof hex == "object" && hex.hasOwnProperty("_tc_id")) {
   alert("no color available; return a default such as fill:'none'");
}
```

like [in this fork the fiddle post in the question](http://jsfiddle.net/TUdzS/2/)

Comment: **spectrum color picker** uses **tinycolor** as you can read in the [events section of the documentation](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) we need to use **color.toHexString()** i.e:  `change: function(color) { color.toHexString(); // #ff0000 }`

Comment: I'll discard the buggy entries, toHexString works and now I understand what was happening.Thanks!

Comment: it work for fabric color with this  "#"+color.toHex()